# input element's maxLength attribute works weird in safari browser when inputting emoji(image character)

Tags: javascript, html, safari

This is a really simple code：

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>if you input emoji(like:) into the input element below</div>
        <div>you will be able to input only 4 emoji in chrome and firefox,the limited length is 8,it's ok</div>
        <div>but when using safari,you can input 8 emoji,and got the length of 8,it's weird</div>
        <input id='input' maxlength="8">
        <script>
          document.getElementById('input'),addEventListener('input',function(e){
            console.log(e.target.value);
            console.log(e.target.value.length);
          })
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

the safari browser can input 8 emoji(with length 16),so I have to listen the input event and do substring especially in safari to ensure it works accord with firefox and chrome, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: in safari can input 8 emoji got 16 length(in the third div it should be 'and got the length of 16')